# jquery add a space before and after forward slash?

Tags: jquery

is it possible to use jquery to find a forward slash "/" in a string and then add a space on either side of it? I'm pulling in content and don't have access to change this particular content, but I'd like there to be spaces before and after the /.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use replace function. example is here http://jsfiddle.net/xgTxK/3/

```
var str = 'hsab bvnbv/fnmn';
str = str.replace(/\//g," / ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be doable with .replace:

```
var myString = "hey/there";
var newString = myString.replace(/\//, " / ");
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pe37q/) to demonstrate - not sure if this is what you're looking for.